# Laravel select2 require/ import

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to require/ import select2 into the project but unsuccessfully.

Tried these two always getting `$('#state').select2` is not a function. When I include select2 in standard `<script>` tag, everything works.

```
require('./bootstrap');

import 'select2';

$('#state').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});
```

and

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.select2 = require('select2/dist/js/select2.min.js');

$('#state').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I using select2 with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473207/how-can-i-using-select2-with-webpack)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `laravel mix` after you install `select2` using npm

```
npm i select2
```

You can simply add it to your `app.js`

```
require('select2');
```

Or

```
window.select2 = require('select2');
```

Comment: Add @import 'select2'; in sass/app.scss