# select2 does not display correctly (Using cdn)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, jquery-select2

I'm trying to complete my website with some java's plugin, I'm on Symfony 4 and I use the CDN bootstrap twitter.

When I put the select2 plugin into the templates all is working properly, the select2 plugin does apply correctly.

However I don't want to load select2 directly from the templates I want to run it from `app.js` but it didn't work properly, the select2 plugin is activated but it's weird, I'll show you the result below.

[image]

**There is my app.js code:**

```
let $ = require('jquery');

require('../css/app.css');
require('select2');

$('select').select2();


console.log('Hello Webpack Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');
```

I'm sorry for my bad English, I'll thank you all for reading my post to the end!

Comment: You may need to also include the select2 css. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473207/how-can-i-using-select2-with-webpack

Comment: Thanks you for you fast reply:edit ! I tryed the new code, but with no succes :/ my code is now let $ = require('jquery');

require('../css/app.css');
require('select2');
require('select2/dist/css/select2.css')

$('select').select2()

Comment: It seems like my css is not know by app.js

Comment: If you're using webpack make sure you also have [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add 3 of the following references

```js
$('select').select2({ width: '100%', placeholder: "Select an Option", allowClear: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<select id='myselect'>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Well its a little bit better, now the search field is displaying but still not correctly  https://imgur.com/8Wi4qUc

Comment: Yes i it works but i dont want to load it this way, i want to do so with webpack :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this select2 cdn example - https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/select2-option-cdn-31353331

```html
<!doctype html>
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
                                <title>Snippet - BBBootstrap</title>
                                <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
                                <link href='' rel='stylesheet'>
                                <style>body {
    background: #eee
}

.form-control {
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #d2d6de
}

.select2-hidden-accessible {
    border: 0 !important;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0) !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    margin: -1px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px !important
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single,
.select2-selection .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 34px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    padding-right: 10px
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -3px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    color: #444;
    line-height: 28px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single,
.select2-selection .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 40px !important
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px !important;
    right: 1px;
    width: 20px
}</style>
                                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
                                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
                                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
                                <script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() {
$('.select2').select2({
closeOnSelect: false
});
});</script>
                            </head>
                            <body oncontextmenu='return false' class='snippet-body'>
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group"> <label>Minimal</label> <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
                    <option>Alaska</option>
                    <option>California</option>
                    <option>Delaware</option>
                    <option>Tennessee</option>
                    <option>Texas</option>
                    <option>Washington</option>
                </select> </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
            <div class="form-group"> <label>Disabled</label> <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" disabled="" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
                    <option>Alaska</option>
                    <option>California</option>
                    <option>Delaware</option>
                    <option>Tennessee</option>
                    <option>Texas</option>
                    <option>Washington</option>
                </select> </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group"> <label>Multiple</label> <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option>Alabama</option>
                    <option>Alaska</option>
                    <option>California</option>
                    <option>Delaware</option>
                    <option>Tennessee</option>
                    <option>Texas</option>
                    <option>Washington</option>
                </select> </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
            <div class="form-group"> <label>Disabled Result</label> <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
                    <option>Alaska</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">California (disabled)</option>
                    <option>Delaware</option>
                    <option>Tennessee</option>
                    <option>Texas</option>
                    <option>Washington</option>
                </select> </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</div>
                            </body>
                        </html>
```