# Rails 6 + Webpacker: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to get **select2** working in my app, but couldn't able to. I've added it by `yarn add select2`. Below is my code

**javascript/packs/application.js**

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("bootstrap")
require("tempusdominus-bootstrap-4")
require("moment/locale/ja")
require('select2')


// stylesheets
require("../stylesheets/application.scss")

import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "./owl.carousel.min.js";
import 'select2';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.customers-dropdown').select2();
    $("select").change(function(event) {
        $("#extra_price").html(formatCurrency($("#extra_" + $(".select").val()).html()));
        computetotal(event); 
    });

    $('#inlineDatepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: false,
        format: 'L',
        useCurrent: false,
        defaultDate: $('#weekStardate').val(),
    
    });

    $("#inlineDatepicker").on("change.datetimepicker", ({date, oldDate}) => {   
        var fdate = moment(date)        
        $('#weekStardate').val(fdate.format("D/M/YYYY")) 
     })
        
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rails_6_devise_example",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.4-3",
    "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
    "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4": "^5.1.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`. I've looked into many posts and as suggested, I tried to add `import $ from 'jquery';` above `import 'select2';` **which works but that breaks datetimepicker** resulting in `Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).datetimepicker is not a function` I don't have a clue what is happening.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I using select2 with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473207/how-can-i-using-select2-with-webpack)

Comment: @GrzegorzT.No, it doesn't. As I told adding `import $ from 'jquery';` solves the problem but breaks the datetimepicker. I'm looking for a solution which will work for both

Comment: And is it not related to dependencies, and I mean jquery and also versions? See this solution, [webpack-how-to-avoid-multiple-versions-of-jquery](https://makandracards.com/makandra/69621-webpack-how-to-avoid-multiple-versions-of-jquery)
Put some version on the githab, the test one, because now we shoot like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared the code quickly and it works fine. I just added this to the plugins:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  moment: 'moment'
})
```

I also changed the order, because that is what the turbolink wanted ;)

```
require("jquery")
require("bootstrap")
require("tempusdominus-bootstrap-4")
require("moment/locale/ja")
require("turbolinks").start()
require('select2')
```

[image]

Of course there are some bugs but I miss `formatCurrency` but the most important things work :)