# Rails 6.1.3, webpacler, select2, getting error: readyException.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am new with Rails 6 and webpacker. I have created a new app with rails and webpacker, got everything working but when I tried to utilize the select2 I ran into a problem where I get readyException.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function errors and not am not able to submit the selected attribute to the database. I have reviewed and tried several suggestions presented on the web but didn't work. Not sure where I went wrong. Any help is much appreciated. By the way I am using simple_form and Slim.

app/assets/application.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

import "jquery";
import "popper.js";
import "bootstrap";
import "../stylesheets/application"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"
import select2 from 'select2';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';


require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")



Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select').select2();
});
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

the view form
views/users/_form.html.slim

```
    = simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|
      = f.error_notification
      = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?


      .form-inputs.form-group.center-block style="width:240px"
        = f.input_field :first_name,
        placeholder: 'First Name',
        class: 'form-control',
        autofocus: true,
        required: true
      .form-inputs.form-group.center-block style="width:240px"
        = f.input_field :last_name,
        placeholder: 'Last Name',
        class: 'form-control',
        autofocus: true,
        required: true
      .form-inputs.form-group.center-block style="width:240px"
        = f.input_field :email,
        placeholder: 'Email',
        class: 'form-control',
        autofocus: true,
        required: true
      .form-inputs.form-group.center-block style="width:240px"
        = f.select :roles, Role.all.map { |role| role.name }, {include_blank: true, required: true,
        include_hidden: false}, class: 'form-control', input_html: {class: 'select'}


      .form-actions.form-group.center-block style="width:240px"
        button.btn.btn-primary.space-above type="submit" Save
        = link_to "Cancel", admin_users_path, class: 'btn btn-default space-left'
```

Comment: Does this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473207/how-can-i-using-select2-with-webpack help?

Comment: Thanks, it was partially helpful when I added import $ from 'jquery' it got rid off the readyException.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(…).select2 is not a function . However, the selection is not getting submitted into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be causing issues by importing jquery twice.

Remove these lines:

```
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

These are duplicating imports on lines above and (I think) the second `require("jquery")` could be clobbering the select2 plugin.

Also, you're not using the local `select2` variable from the import. This should be sufficient:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'select2'

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(...).select2()
})
```

I have a branch in a demo repo that has a working example https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/select2

Comment: Thanks roosts for your feedback, I have modified application.js as per your suggestion, it did get rid off the Uncaught TypeError: $(…).select2 is not a function error, however I am not sure why the selected element in select does not go through. the following is patch portion on (rails s). One thing I notices is Unpermitted parameter: : roles:

Comment: Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"kirk1", "last_name"=>"Douglas2", "email"=>"fkas@hotmail.com", "roles"=>"guest"}, "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `restrict_to_admin'
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳
Unpermitted parameter: :roles