# "default" is not exported by "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js" when building with laravel 9 and vite

Tags: laravel, npm, jquery-select2, vite

I have a Laravel 9 app. I am trying to get `select2` to work however, when I do `npm run build` I get the error:

> RollupError: "default" is not exported by "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js", imported by "resources/js/app.js".

I installed `select2` using the following:

```
npm install select2 --save-dev
```

Then I added the following lines in my `app.js` file after the jquery import:

```js
import select2 from "select2"

select2()
```

Everything seems to be fine in dev mode. However, as soon as I try to build it, I get the error mentioned above. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Having the exact same issue. It makes sense, you'd just need to `import 'select2';` but with Vite that doesn't actually seem to work.

Comment: Can you please share complete `app.js` and `vite.config.js`? Am using select2 in Laravel 9 with Livewire component and it's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, `select2` is a jQuery plugin and does not use `ES6` modules. If no `ES6` means No support for `export default`

---

To use this,

**Import it** with a jQuery structure.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**In code**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import 'select2'; // Modifies the global jQuery object.

$('select').select2();
```

can try this too [How can I using select2 with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38476232/4595675)

**If you have CSS**, you can add in main CSS or SASS(ex: `app.scss`)

```
@import "~select2/dist/css/select2.min.css";
```

Finally, run

```
npm run build
```

---

In case you need CDN [Using Select2 from a CDN](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 0):

As select2 does not support ES6 we can use **import * as select2 from 'select2'** in app.js

I'm using Laravel 9, Vite and Sass; this is my full working config in app.js to import jQuery and select2:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = $;
import * as select2 from 'select2';
select2($, jQuery);
```

This is my vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";  

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        }),
        laravel({input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js',], refresh: true}),
    ]
});
```

Finally remember to add type="module" to any script elements in your blade templates if you are calling jQuery there.

Some of this configuration may not be needed for select2 to work but I have other packages that require jQuery and so I have included all configuration that works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try this
`import $ from 'jquery';`
`import 'select2';`

`// Optional: Import select2 CSS if needed import 'select2/dist/css/select2.min.css';` 
`// Initialize select2 $(document).ready(function() { $('select').select2() })`
than
npm run dev